# mapstruct: update existing field of entity using data from DTO

Tags: mapstruct

I recently added mapStruct in my project. This framework is cool, but I can not figure out one thing.

This is my case: I have `Profile` entity and field with the `Person` type. I want to update it using `ProfileDto`. I am using `void fromDto(ProfileDto dto, @MappingTarget Profile entity)` method for this. The problem is that mapper always **create new Person** instead of using person from `profile` entity

My entity is:

```
public class Profile  {
    private Person person;
    .. setters, getters and  constructors 
}

public class Person extends AbstractEntity {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    .. setters, getters and  constructors 
}
```

Dto

```
public class ProfileDto  extends AbstractDto {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    .. setters, getters and  constructors 
}
```

my mapper

```
public abstract class ProfileMapper {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "name", source = "entity.person.name"),
            @Mapping(target = "surname", source = "entity.person.surname")

    })
    public abstract ProfileDto toDto(Profile entity);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration(name = "toDto")
    public abstract void fromDto(ProfileDto dto, @MappingTarget Profile entity);
}
```

generated code

```
      @Override
        public void fromDto(ProfileDto dto, Profile entity) {
            if ( dto == null ) {
                return;
            }
            Person person = new Person();
            entity.setPerson( person );
...
```

I don't need to create new instance of person here

**person = new Person();**

I what somehow to replace this string with:

**person = entity.getPerson()**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue, see [#1011](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1011). This has been improved in `1.2.0`(at the time of writing 11.07.2017 the latest version is `1.2.0.Beta3`). You should try the latest version, it should work as expected.

Comment: Filip thank you. do you know when will be release 1.2.0.Final verson?

Comment: We are still not sure. The CR1 will be released really soon (this week maybe)